Webpack not watching SCSS glob imported files
I am using webpack to compile my scss files which works fine when initially running npx webpack or npx webpack --watch.
When using npx webpack --watch, only my declared SCSS file (app.scss) in my index.js is watched and hot loads fine.
My @import[ed] SCSS files from app.scss aren't being watched, however if I make changes to these imports then save app.scss, it recompiles everything.
Is there a way to make it so that my imported files are also watched
index.js
import 'src/styles/app.scss';

app.scss
@import '../settings/**/*.scss';
@import '../components/**/*.scss';

webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const globImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'scripts/index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                importer: globImporter()
              },
              sourceMap: true,
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles/app.css',
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ]
  },
  watch: true,
  mode: 'development'
};

If it's any help, I'm running:

Running Win 11 Home 22631.3737
Node v20.13.1
PHP 8.1.25 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2023 08:06:57)
npm 10.5.2

and package.json:
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.2",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.11.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "node-sass-glob-importer": "^3.0.2",
    "open": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.11",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.3",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.92.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  },

Been scratching my head for a while.. many thanks!
